# How to show TabLayout programmatically, which is previously hide via app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"

Tags: android

Currently, I hide `TabLayout` during scrolling (My `ViewPager` contains multiple fragments, which in-turn contains `RecyclerView`).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="?attr/portfolioTabIndicatorColor" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" -->
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />    
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

When I swipe the `ViewPager` to selected `Fragment`, I would like to show `TabLayout` again programmatically, without perform any scrolling. May I know how can I achieve so?